# Select on IF or is there an easier way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 tables.

PART

USER

DOCUMENT

```
       ╔═════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════╗
       ║ Part Number ║ Keyed Name         ║ Classification ║
       ╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════╣
       ║ 456789      ║ 1/4" Bolt          ║ Buy            ║
       ╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════╣
       ║ 224567      ║ 1/4" Washer        ║ Buy            ║
       ╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════╣
       ║ 119011      ║ Leg Brace Assembly ║ Make           ║
       ╚═════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════╝


       ╔═════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════╗
       ║ User ID ║ Keyed Name   ║ Email             ║
       ╠═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
       ║ 9999111 ║ Bob Johnson  ║ Bob@comail.com    ║
       ╠═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
       ║ 1119999 ║ Lauren Halls ║ LHalls@comail.com ║
       ╠═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
       ║ 1199199 ║ Mike Taylor  ║ MTay@comail.com   ║
       ╚═════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════╝

       ╔═════════════════╦════════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
       ║ Document Number ║ Keyed Name         ║ Created By   ║ Modified By  ║
       ╠═════════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
       ║ 123456          ║ Random 1           ║ Bob Johnson  ║ Lauren Halls ║
       ╠═════════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
       ║ 119011_DDM      ║ Leg Brace Assembly ║ Lauren Halls ║ Lauren Halls ║
       ╠═════════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
       ║ 123456_DDM      ║ Random 1           ║ Bob Johnson  ║ Mike Taylor  ║
       ╠═════════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
       ║ 335678          ║ Random 3           ║ Bob Johnson  ║ Mike Taylor  ║
       ╚═════════════════╩════════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

My query looks like this:

```
select
d1.KEYED_NAME as "Document Number",
d1.CSH_PLI_DUMMY_REVISION as "Revision",
d1.CREATED_ON as "Created On",
d1.MODIFIED_ON as "Modified On",
d1.RELEASE_DATE as "Release Date",
d1.[STATE] as "State",
p1.KEYED_NAME as "Product",
d1.CLASSIFICATION as "Item Type",
u1.KEYED_NAME as "Created By",
u1.KEYED_NAME as "Modified By",
d1.IS_CURRENT as "Current"

from innovator.DOCUMENT as d1
LEFT JOIN innovator.[USER] as u1 ON (d1.CREATED_BY_ID = u1.id)
LEFT JOIN innovator.PRODUCT as p1 ON (p1.id = d1.CP_PRODUCT)


where d1.IS_CURRENT = '1'
    AND d1.[ITEM_NUMBER] LIKE '%_DDM'
    or EXISTS (select 1 from innovator.DOCUMENT d2 LEFT JOIN innovator.PRODUCT p1 ON (d1.CP_PRODUCT = p1.id)
                where d1.IS_CURRENT = 1 AND d1.[ITEM_NUMBER] + '_DDM' = d2.[ITEM_NUMBER])
order by d1.KEYED_NAME ASC, d1.CSH_PLI_DUMMY_REVISION DESC
```

Right now the query will find the Document and it's corresponding _DDM number. However what I have been failing to get is that the query also needs to find a PART number if it has a _DDM in the Document table. From the examples given the query needs to find Part Number 119011 because there is a 119011_DDM in the Document Table which does not have its own Document Number 119011.

I have tried to UNION ALL the query above to a select statement for the PART table. I have tried a couple variants on a NOT EXISTS, but I am sure I am using the syntax incorrectly.

Basically I am stumped again.

Comment: The data you showed us does not match the columns to which you refer in your query.  It would be much easier to help you if you instead showed us sample data matching the query, along with the expected output from that query.

Comment: What is the relation between Part and other two tables? Once you define it  It would be easy to apply to join as you are doing currently.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal The relation from PART to Document is they both can possibly have a Keyed Name in common. The USER appears on both tables as the Created_BY_ID and MODIFIED_BY_ID which corresponds to the USER ID.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close on this. You can use JOIN with OR clause, so you can match part with either Document Number or DDM, with part-id.

```
select
d1.KEYED_NAME as "Document Number",
d1.CSH_PLI_DUMMY_REVISION as "Revision",
d1.CREATED_ON as "Created On",
d1.MODIFIED_ON as "Modified On",
d1.RELEASE_DATE as "Release Date",
d1.[STATE] as "State",
p1.KEYED_NAME as "Product",
d1.CLASSIFICATION as "Item Type",
u1.KEYED_NAME as "Created By",
u1.KEYED_NAME as "Modified By",
d1.IS_CURRENT as "Current"

from innovator.DOCUMENT as d1
LEFT JOIN innovator.[USER] as u1 ON (d1.CREATED_BY_ID = u1.id)
LEFT JOIN innovator.PRODUCT as p1 ON (p1.id = d1.CP_PRODUCT) OR (p1.id + '_DDM' = d1.[ITEM_NUMBER])

where d1.IS_CURRENT = '1'
AND d1.[ITEM_NUMBER] LIKE '%_DDM'
or EXISTS (select 1 from innovator.DOCUMENT d2 where d2.IS_CURRENT = 1 AND d2.[ITEM_NUMBER] + '_DDM' = d1.[ITEM_NUMBER])
order by d1.KEYED_NAME ASC, d1.CSH_PLI_DUMMY_REVISION DESC;
```

Comment: This does not deliver the right results to me. The goal is to have a return of all _DDM Document Numbers, and with them either the corresponding Document Number or the Part Number.

Comment: I have updated the query with more understanding. However, if still has missing pieces, that can be resolved if you can provide the complete table structures. The columns you are using in the query is not matching with the table structure you have provided. Its hard to guess with incomplete information.